# issue with Angular 2 forms

Tags: angular, browser-sync, lite-server

I deployed angular application  , and made the lite-server running forever using forever.js . now the issue is if two different users are using the application and filling the form, then the data the first user is typing in is visible to second user who opened the application in his browser on different machine.  What could be the reason for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the behavior of [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) which [light-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) is based on. This is used mainly for testing purpose. You should use other servers for production.

From `BrowserSync` page:

> Interaction sync
>
> Your scroll, click, refresh and form actions are
> mirrored between browsers while you test.